# Recover modified txt file

Tags: data-recovery

My system went crazy and put nulls in one file. I know what text should be in this file, so I need a solution to search through the HDD for the text that's missing.

Is there a way to recover the overwritten txt file?

Comment: chances are low on this

Comment: @Michael Unless you know how the software that changed the file contents works, there's no way to say for sure. Some programs perform atomic saves by saving to a temporary file, removing the original, and then renaming the new file. In this case, it's quite possible to find the original file.

Comment: Well if I had something what can search for text located on hdd, I think it will be good for me, but it would have to search sector by sector

Answer (score 1):

The best method is to restore the file from one of your daily or weekly backups.

The second best way is probably to use something like [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva). Tools like this probably can't recover the overwritten sectors but might find an older version of the text file if you are very lucky and edited the file a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use [WinHex](http://winhex.com/winhex/) and search for text in the file.

From the WinHex site:

> WinHex is in its core a universal hexadecimal editor, particularly
>   helpful in the realm of computer forensics, data recovery, low-level
>   data processing, and IT security. An advanced tool for everyday and
>   emergency use: inspect and edit all kinds of files, recover deleted
>   files or lost data from hard drives with corrupt file systems or from
>   digital camera cards.